# How to clone a nested list in Python?

Tags: list, for-loop, python-2.7, clone

I am reading "How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python 2nd Edition documentation". At the end of [Chapter 9](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch09.html) there is this exercise 11, which asks you to
write Python code to make the doctest pass.

My initial solution:

```
def add_column(matrix):
"""
  >>> m = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
  >>> add_column(m)
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
  >>> n = [[3, 2], [5, 1], [4, 7]]
  >>> add_column(n)
  [[3, 2, 0], [5, 1, 0], [4, 7, 0]]
  >>> n
  [[3, 2], [5, 1], [4, 7]]
"""
result = matrix[:]
for index in range(len(matrix)):
    result[index] += [0]
return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

However this code didn't pass the second test. I changed the body of the **for** loop to the following:

```
result[index] = result[index] + [0]
```

and the code now passes all the tests. But I can't understand how this change in the code solved the problem. I thought `result[index] = result[index] + [0]` is the explicit form of `result[0] += [0]`, so why the behaviour is different?

Having compared my answer to that code that is provided in the solutions, I suspect the problem might be in how I cloned the list. In the solutions it's done like this: `result = [d[:] for d in matrix]`, in which case my initial **for** loop  would work. But why `result = matrix[:]` isn't working? Is it creating an alias, not a new object?

Also, can someone explain how `[d[:] for d in matrix]` is parsed and when such syntax is used? I haven't seen this way of using the **for** loop before and it hasn't been explained/demonstrated in the lessons.

Answer (score 0):

The list isn't being cloned for the following reason:

```
result = matrix[:]
```

does indeed copy the list; but you haven't copied the list *items*. Python handles list items by reference, so `result[0]` and `matrix[0]` will still be pointing to the same list object, even thought `result` and `matrix` are different lists.

`[d[:] for d in matrix]` clones both the main list and the list elements because it iterates over `matrix` and creates a copy of each element (rather than using the reference to that element) in the new list.

You can also use the `copy` module, which is especially useful because it handles dicts as well, and with `copy.deepcopy` you can clone multi-dimensional lists of an unknown depth: http://docspy2zh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/copy.html (but fair enough if that is outside the scope of what you're trying to learn here).

As for the difference between '+=' and '= ... + ...', I confess that I am slightly surprised as well. In a situation like this, I would tend towards using `result[index].append(0)`, which would avoid that ambiguity; but that, of course, is not an answer.